# SSL: Support both iOS9 and older versions of Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, ios9

The issue that I am facing is I am trying to support both iOS9, and older versions of Internet Explorer (as old as Internet Explorer 8).

iOS9 has some strict constraints such as the fact that perfect forward secrecy must be enabled on the server it is trying to contact. I've compiled a list of ciphers to the best of my ability to accomodate this, but cannot at the same time have a list of ciphers that supports Internet Explorer. I've been using this cipher list:

> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CDC_SHA SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

This cipher list provides perfect forward secrecy and allows iOS9 to communicate with the server. However, in order to get Internet Explorer 8 and above to work, I have to include

> SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Which of course breaks perfect forward secrecy and thus iOS9. I am aware that I can have ATS disabled on iOS9 to work around this, but I would rather not if I do not have to.

Is there some combination of ciphers that I can use to enable the use of Internet Explorer 8 and above and also provide perfect forward secrecy? Or do we need to disable ATS on iOS9 until we can move the company off of Internet Explorer 8?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I enabled all DHE and ECDHE cipher suites and managed to have all browsers supported as I had expected. Your mileage may vary (depending on what cipher suites you have available to you), but the following cipher suite list is what I  used:

[image]